# What do I have to do to get my ASP.NET MasterPage to work on my server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I followed some examples in my ASP.NET 4.5 in C# book for Master Pages. So I made a more complex site using them, and it all works locally. But when I push it to my remote server, it is saying the file cannot be found. So I made a more basic master page in Visual Studio 2015 to check. And it works locally, but when pushed to the remote server, it still does not work. I couldn't find any answers online either. I've tried some different urls thinking I was using the wrong url too. I've used 

myWebSite.com/TestFolder/MasterPage.master

myWebSite.com/TestFolder/

myWebSite.com/TestFolder/MasterPage

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code for my master page looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Tester</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a test of the master page.</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you were trying to do, but for future reference, you never actually navigate to a master page. It's basically a glorified template file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That analogy does help me understand better. Since it wasn't finding the file, I kind of started to doubt that I was trying to navigate to it correctly, so I tried to navigate to it using any extension I thought it could possibly be.

Comment: Assuming you're using Visual Studio, the tooling is there to make using your master page easier. When you want to add another page, you can right-click the master page and choose "Add content page". You can also right click on the project, select "Add new item", and choose "Webform using Master page". The editor templates will add the necessary bindings to ensure the master page gets applied to the content page.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it. I made sure that the file path to the CodeFile in the header was "./MasterPage.master.cs" and the MasterPageFile reference in the header of the content page was "./MasterPage.master" not "~/MasterPage.master".

The url also worked just as myWebSite.com/

Thank you for the help anyways. Much appreciated.